# IIS 8.5 & 7.5 - Application Pool Recycling

Tags: windows, iis-7.5, application-pool

We have an enterprise web application developed in mixed ASP Classic (VB Script & Visual Basic 6.0 ActiveX COM Components) and ASP.Net 4.0. This application is hosted on Windows Server 2012R2, IIS 8.5 and 7.5 on Windows Server 2008R2 and Application Pool Memory Limit 450MB.

Somehow application pool is being recycled after every 4 to 5 minutes in peak hours because of memory exceeds the limit. If we increase the memory limit application is start getting slow or completely stuck when memory reaches at certain level.

I have tried the Microsoft Debug Diagnostic tool to take memory dumps and analysis but unfortunately didn't get any clue that where is the leaks.

Can anyone suggest a better memory profiling tool that may help to identify the root cause or any other directions which we may follow to identify the problem.

Regards,

Shahid

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 ships with IIS 8.5, not 7.5. Who decided to set memory limit to 4.5MB？That's ridiculously small for typical web applications.

Comment: I am sorry, yes it is 8.5 on Windows Server 2012R2 and 7.5 on 2008R2. There was a typo for the memory limit, it is 450MB not 4.5MB.

Comment: Please consider formatting the question into several paragraphs. That makes it much easier to read. Ask for recommendation on SO is off-topic.